# Annotating a qgraph

Tags: r, graph, tooltip

I am using the folowing:

```
Package: SVGAnnotation, Version: 0.93-1
Package: qgraph,   Version: 1.0.5-2
```

My goal is to add tooltips to the nodes of the qgraph.

The svgPlot function creates the XML document in the `svgdoc1` variable

```
svgdoc1 <- svgPlot(qgraph(cov2cor(matrix1), filetype = '', color = color1, 
           vsize = vsize1,labels=labels1, layout='spring', 
           minimum = 0.04, bidirectional=TRUE, arrows=FALSE))
```

The `svgdoc1` document can be saved to the file and a plot can be viewed in a web browser.
Then I tryed adding tooltips

```
addToolTips(svgdoc1, tooltips1)
```

where tooltips1 is a vector of strings.

I got the following error:

```
Error evaluating: addToolTips(svgdoc1, tooltips1):Error in tmp[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I have found that the error had actually happened in the `getPlotRegionNodes` function
because the xml document doesn't have the "clip-path" attribute.

Is it possible to annotate a qgraph with tooltips using the svgPlot function as described above?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a SVG picture with mouse-over tooltips is build in functionality (using `RSVGTipsDevice`):

```
library("qgraph")
qgraph(matrix(1,3,3),filetype="svg",tooltips=c("foo","bar","gux"))
```

Here `tooltips` can be assigned a vector with tooltips for each node.

Another option for tooltips is using `tikzdevice` to create a `.tex` file (LaTeX) that can be compiled in a pdf document with mouseover tooltips (works best in Adobe reader). To do that a hotfix (since `tikzDevice` is no longer on CRAN) is available at my website: http://sachaepskamp.com/qgraph